# Intervention Image with Laravel Resource API

Tags: php, laravel, intervention, laravel-api

Is it possible to return a image created on the fly with Laravel API Resources without saving it?
Tried in controller

```
$sum = Product::where('slug', $product)->first();

        $img = Image::make('image_path')->resize(400, 400);
        $img->text(name, 205, 138, function($font) {
            $font->file('fonts/BostonHeavy.woff');
            $font->size(42);
            $font->color('#ffffff');
            $font->align('center');
            $font->valign('top');
        });

       return (new ProductResource($sum))->foo($img);
```

Laravel API Resource

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProductResource extends JsonResource
{
    protected $image;

    public function foo($value){
        $this->image = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'image' => $this->image,
        ];
    }

}
```

what gets returned

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Such a pickle",
        "image": {
            "encoded": "",
            "mime": "image/jpeg",
            "dirname": null,
            "basename": null,
            "extension": null,
            "filename": null
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously is not working in the docs it says to use return $img->response('jpg'); which on it's own works but I want to added it to the response instead of doing two get requests.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to return something you can use inside a `src` attribute in an `img` tag. Try this:

```php
$imgBase64 = (string) $img->encode('data-url');
return (new ProductResource($sum))->foo($imgBase64);
```

Then, use that string in an `img` tag with the appropriate syntax:

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <<yourEncodedStringHere>>" />
```